# Cannot bind grid to viewmodel - no data appears in the grid

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Please see the XAML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:PersonViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="First Name" />
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="Surname" />
            <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="Date Of Birth" />
        </Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding people}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Surname}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Age}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

and the View Model:

```
public class PersonViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Person> people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        public PersonViewModel()
        {
            people.Add(new Person { Age = 36, FirstName = "Andrew", Surname = "Smith" });
            people.Add(new Person { Age = 65, FirstName = "David", Surname = "White" });
            people.Add(new Person { Age = 39, FirstName = "Bert", Surname = "Edwards" });
        }
    }
```

Only the column headings display.  Why does the data not display?

I have spent all afternoon trying to get this to work.  I have read lots of different answers, however I still cannot get any data to display.

Comment: first, `people` is not a public property.  You can only bind to public properties.  Second, the grid(s) inside your template are completely independent of the other grids on your page, so you will also need to define Row and Columns for each.

Comment: @Jason, I have made it a public property and now the data appears - thanks.  Can you clarify what you mean by our second statement? +1.

Comment: Inside your template you have a grid, but you do not have any RowDefinition or ColumnDefintions specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the Grid Column Definitions (if it is the same as the header, so your xaml should look like this:

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="* />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="* />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="* />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="First Name" />
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="Surname" />
            <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="Date Of Birth" />
        </Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding people}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="* />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="* />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="* />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Surname}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Age}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Could you have a look at my similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57744953/passing-a-dynamic-value-to-an-event-handler-when-a-row-is-clicked