# Passing a dynamic value to an event handler when a row is clicked

Tags: c#, xamarin

Please see the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:PersonViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
            <ListView.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.BindingContext>
                        <local:PersonViewModel />
                    </Grid.BindingContext>


                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="Id" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="First Name" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="Surname" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="4" Text="Date Of Birth" />
                </Grid>
            </ListView.Header>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Id}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Surname}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Age}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

and the view model below:

```
public class PersonViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Person> _people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        public ObservableCollection<Person> People
        {
            get { return _people; }
        }

        public PersonViewModel()
        {
            _people.Add(new Person { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Age = 36, FirstName = "Andrew", Surname = "Smith" });
            _people.Add(new Person { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Age = 65, FirstName = "David", Surname = "White" });
            _people.Add(new Person { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Age = 39, FirstName = "Bert", Surname = "Edwards" });
        }
    }
```

It works as expected i.e. the grid is added to the page.  If a user clicks on one of the rows; I want the ID of that row to be passed to an event handler.  How do I do this.  I have spent the last three hours researching this, however I have not found an answer.  The closest I have found is this: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23002/how-do-you-detect-a-grid-click-tap.  However, in this case a static value is passed and not a dynamic value.

Comment: Within the `ItemSelected` event there is the `SelectedItem` that contains a ref to your `PersonViewModel` object

Comment: Then add it to the People class.  You are only going to get the object passed   Maybe you want the event to be the DataRow instead of a Person.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want the ID of the object, and not the row (since that wouldn't be relevant imho)

So, Listview has a ItemTapped Event:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" 
        ItemTapped="TappedListView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
```

And, in your Page.xaml.cs

```
private void TappedListView(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
     var yourItem = e.Item as Person;
         var id = yourItem.Id;
}
```

You can read more about Listview Interactivity in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity)

Comment: Thanks.  The compilation error I get with this on second to last line is: "embedded statement cannot be declarative or labelled statement".  Adding brackets sorts it but I am not sure why?

Comment: That is the null check. I don't know the type of Id,so , you can declare it before, or just remove the checking.

Comment: The type of is: guid.  I skill ger the error id i say: Guid id = yourItem.Id;

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said, there is selecteditem property in ListView, the type is Person model, you can create person model in PersonViewmodel, binding to ListView SelectedItem and implement INotifyPropertyChanged to update when you click ListView Item.

```
 <ListView
            x:Name="listView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding peoples}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding selecteditem}">
            <ListView.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="Id" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="First Name" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="Surname" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="Date Of Birth" />
                </Grid>
            </ListView.Header>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Id}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Surname}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Age}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

public class PersonViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<personmodel> peoples { get; set; }

    private personmodel _selecteditem;
    public personmodel selecteditem
    {
        get { return _selecteditem; }
        set
        {
            _selecteditem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("selecteditem");
        }
    }     
    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        peoples = new ObservableCollection<personmodel>();
        peoples.Add(new personmodel { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Age = 36, FirstName = "Andrew", Surname = "Smith" });
        peoples.Add(new personmodel { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Age = 65, FirstName = "David", Surname = "White" });
        peoples.Add(new personmodel { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Age = 39, FirstName = "Bert", Surname = "Edwards" });
        selecteditem = peoples[0];
    }
}


public class ViewModelBase: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

So if you want to pass clicked row Id to event handler, you just pass

```
selecteditem.Id
```